# Unity error when placing a random movement script on a sphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navmesh

I believe the NavMesh is not being placed in coordination with the sphere object would be my guess. This is the script the start of the script that I have on the sphere.

```
NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
    public float timeForNewPath;
    bool inCoRoutine;

    void Start()
    {
        navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

        // Find a valid position on the NavMesh
        NavMeshHit hit;
        if (NavMesh.SamplePosition(transform.position, out hit, 1.0f, NavMesh.AllAreas))
        {
            // If a valid position was found, move the agent to that position
            navMeshAgent.Warp(hit.position);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("No valid position on the NavMesh found close to the agent's starting position");
        }
    }
```

The else statement is always returned.

I am not sure what to do to get past this issue, any help is appreciated.

Comment: what  is the error, and on which line

Comment: Please describe you problem in detail.

Comment: The problem is the else block is being accessed in the code that I sent.

Comment: so your navmesh is >1f away from your position..

Comment: @BugFinder is there a line of code that I could add into my start function that would align my Navmesh to the position?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your object far away than **1.0f** distance from the navmesh surface.
You can try to increasing **1.0f** to a bigger value, for example, **10.0f**. It will find nearest position anyway.

Also, check, are you baked your NavMesh surface on the scene already? Sometimes it can be a problem :)